# iOS image comparison algorithm to find the differences in two very similar but different photos

Tags: iphone, algorithm, ios, compare, photo

My use case is that I have two images (photos) that are almost identical but do have some differences throughout.  They won't be perfectly aligned, but they will be pretty darn close to each other.  As a rough estimate, I'd expect to find a half dozen or less differences scattered randomly throughout a pair of 640x480 photos.  The size of each difference would be roughly 20x20 px but there may be some odd shaped ones in there like 200x30 or so.

The algorithm will probably need to do some kind of blurring or fuzzy comparison or use "shaders" and "filters".  Unfortunately, this is nowhere near my area of expertise.  I've seen some libraries in my google searches, but nothing that looks like it would run on an iPhone.

Ideally, I'm looking for a working library, tutorial, or example code that can run on iOS.

Comment: When you say "not perfectly aligned", does this mean that pixel (0,0) of the one image is not likely to perfectly align with pixel (0,0) of the next image?  If that's the case, then it's a bit harder....

Comment: Exactly.  Not only will (0,0) not be perfectly aligned on both images, but they will be photos from two different snaps, so there will be some noise variation and such.  Luckily I can be certain that the camera angle and lighting conditions won't change in between.

Comment: Bear in mind that iOS has a BSD layer underneath the Cocoa & Foundation stuff, so many libraries written for Linux/Unix will build under iOS with minimal porting.

Answer (score 0):

The basic comparison may be the eigenvector comparison. But there is nice tutorial for java devs, [here](http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp). May be helpful.